# buyer who bought "iPhone" returns empty

Tags: mysql, sql

tables:

```
create table product (
product_id int,
product_name varchar(50),
unit_price int);

insert into product values
(1, "S8", 1000),
(2, "G4", 800),
(3, "iPhone", 1400);

create table sales (
seller_id int,
product_id int,
buyer_id int,
sale_date date,
quantity int,
price int);

insert into sales values
(1, 1, 1, "2019-01-21", 2, 2000),
(1, 2, 2, "2019-02-17", 1, 800),
(2, 1, 3, "2019-06-02", 1, 800),
(3, 3, 3, "2019-05-13", 2, 2800);
```

if I want to find the buyers who bought "iPhone", I get empty when using this query:

```
select s.buyer_id, p.product_name from sales s join product p
on s.product_id = p.product_id
group by s.buyer_id
having p.product_name = "iPhone";
```

if I wnat to find buyers who bought other items like "S8", I can definitely get it by using the same query:

```
select s.buyer_id, p.product_name from sales s join product p
on s.product_id = p.product_id
group by s.buyer_id
having p.product_name = "S8";
```

result as expected:

```
buyer_id  |  productname
1         |  S8
3         |  S8
```

what's wrong with iPhone? I use MariaDB 10.3
Thanks

Comment: "definitely" um, nope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter *before* aggregating:

```
select s.buyer_id
from sales s join
     product p
     on s.product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_name = 'iPhone'
group by s.buyer_id;
```

Or use an aggregation function that counts the matches:

```
having sum(p.product_name = 'iPhone') > 0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how `having sum(p.product_name = 'iPhone') > 0` works?

Comment: @PirateX . . . MySQL allows you to use `SUM()` on boolean expressions -- counting the number of true values.  So that expression is checking that there is at least one `product_name = 'iPhone'` in each group (i.e. `buyer_id`) in the result set.