# Unioning - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table: Movies

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| movie_id      | int     |
| title         | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

movie_id is the primary key for this table.
title is the name of the movie.
Table: Users

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | int     |
| name          | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

user_id is the primary key for this table.
Table: Movie_Rating

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| movie_id      | int     |
| user_id       | int     |
| rating        | int     |
| created_at    | date    |
+---------------+---------+
```

(movie_id, user_id) is the primary key for this table.
This table contains the rating of a movie by a user in their review.
created_at is the user's review date.

Write the following SQL query:

Find the name of the user who has rated the greatest number of the movies.
In case of a tie, return lexicographically smaller user name.

Find the movie name with the highest average rating in February 2020.
In case of a tie, return lexicographically smaller movie name.

Query is returned in 2 rows, the query result format is in the folowing example:

Movies table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| movie_id    |  title       |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | Avengers     |
| 2           | Frozen 2     |
| 3           | Joker        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Users table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| user_id     |  name        |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | Daniel       |
| 2           | Monica       |
| 3           | Maria        |
| 4           | James        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Movie_Rating table:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| movie_id    | user_id      | rating       | created_at  |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1            | 3            | 2020-01-12  |
| 1           | 2            | 4            | 2020-02-11  |
| 1           | 3            | 2            | 2020-02-12  |
| 1           | 4            | 1            | 2020-01-01  |
| 2           | 1            | 5            | 2020-02-17  | 
| 2           | 2            | 2            | 2020-02-01  | 
| 2           | 3            | 2            | 2020-03-01  |
| 3           | 1            | 3            | 2020-02-22  | 
| 3           | 2            | 4            | 2020-02-25  | 
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Result table:

```
+--------------+
| results      |
+--------------+
| Daniel       |
| Frozen 2     |
+--------------+
```

Daniel and Maria have rated 3 movies ("Avengers", "Frozen 2" and "Joker") but Daniel is smaller lexicographically.
Frozen 2 and Joker have a rating average of 3.5 in February but Frozen 2 is smaller lexicographically.

Here is my solution:

```
(
  select top 1 u.name as results 
  from users as u
  join movie_rating as m on u.user_id = m.user_id
  group by user_id
  order by count(rating) desc, name
)
union all
(
  select top 1 m.title as results 
  from movies as m
  join movie_rating as r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id
  where CONVERT(varchar(7), r.created_at, 121) = '2020-02'
  group by m.title
  order by avg(rating) desc, m.title
);
```

I get this error that I can't figure it out

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)

any idea and how to fix it?

Comment: When `union`-ing you can only have a single `order by` which follows the last `union`-ed query.

Comment: Using count(..) and avg(..) is invalid in the order clause. Ordering is done per-row so aggregates don’t make sense there.

Comment: @DaleK The TOP 1 (any TOP usage) allows the order by in the subqueries. It would also be a different error message.

Comment: @user2864740 but they're not sub-queries, the brackets are also incorrect syntax since OP wants to union them.

Comment: Which is probably the crux..

Comment: @DaleK I think adding the parentheses for the two sub-queries should allow the order by in each query, isn't it?

Comment: No - not when you are trying to union the results together.

Comment: @user2864740 since I already have group by so I think I can use aggregation in order by, am I wrong? I know I can do this in mysql for sure. is this different in MS SQL?

Comment: What you can do in other database system does not necessary means it will works for `SQL Server`. Please do keep this in mind. All database system are different.

Answer (score 2):

OK I think this might work, as you didn't provide DDL/DML statements I haven't been able to test it.

Points to note:

1. Instead of a sub-query you need a full derived query for each part of the union.
2. For any computed `order by` column you need to compute it in the select and then `order by` the alias.
3. You need to `group by u.[name]` not `u.[user_id]`, you have to `group by` whatever you are selecting.
4. You had some missing aliases which caused an ambiguous column error.
5. If you want to `avg` an `int` column you have to convert it to a `decimal` of some sort to avoid SQL Server automatically rounding it to an `int`.

```
    select results, rating
    from (
      select top 1 u.[name] as results, count(convert(decimal(9,2),m.rating)) rating 
      from users as u
      join movie_rating as m on u.[user_id] = m.[user_id]
      group by u.[name]
      order by rating desc, results asc
    ) X

    union all

    select results, rating
    from (
      select top 1 m.title as results, avg(convert(decimal(9,2),r.rating)) Rating
      from movies as m
      join movie_rating as r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id
      where CONVERT(varchar(7), r.created_at, 121) = '2020-02'
      group by m.title
      order by rating desc, results asc
    ) X;
```

Comment: Thanks. this one resolve the syntax error but the result is not the right answer.

Comment: @JamesWang surely you can adjust the logic to get the correct results now you can see how its done? If not please provide the DDL/DML statements to setup some test data to work on - I'm not spending half an hour typing it out :)

Comment: And when you say "not the right answer" what are you getting vs what are you expecting to get?

Comment: @JamesWang I note you have added DDL/DML statements [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366012/buyer-who-bought-iphone-returns-empty), I recommend getting in the habit of doing that for all your SQL questions as it makes them much easier to answer.

Comment: I think I get the points, thanks. I tried mysql and postgresql and both can have parentheses for two sub-query  between union and it works, so different from ms sql. also mysql and postgresql can have aggregation function in order by when group by exists, another difference from ms sql.

Comment: Yip every RDNMS is different - I assumed that is why you asked a question? Have you got it sorted now? If so what did you have to change from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Per @Dale K, here is revised solution that works.

```
select a.name as results from (
  select top 1 u.name 
  from users as u
  join movie_rating as m on u.user_id = m.user_id
  group by u.name
  order by count(m.rating) desc, u.name
) a
union all
select title as results from (
  select top 1 m.title 
  from movies as m
  join movie_rating as r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id
  where CONVERT(varchar(7), r.created_at, 121) = '2020-02'
  group by m.title
  order by avg(cast(rating as decimal)) desc, m.title
) b;
```